# empty file upload rails jquery uploader

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload, jquery-fileupload-rails

I am using rails jquery upload with paperclip. 
My table gets updated with `created_at` and `uploaded_at` but file_name,file_size and all empty. And i cannot see any files uploaded.

This is the gem i used

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-fileupload-rails'
gem 'paperclip'
```

This is my uploads_controller

```
def create
    @image = Upload.new(upload_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @image.save
        format.html {
          render :json => [@image.to_jq_upload].to_json,
          :content_type => 'text/html',
          :layout => false
        }
        format.json { render json: {files: [@image.to_jq_upload]}, status: :created, location: @image }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @image.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Since i am using rails i used this

```
private
  def upload_params
    params.require(:upload).permit(:post_id,:upload_file_name,:upload_file_size,:upload_content_type,:upload_updated_at)
  end
```

This is my upload model

```
has_attached_file :upload, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }

  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def to_jq_upload
    {
      "name" => read_attribute(:upload_file_name),
      "size" => read_attribute(:upload_file_size),
      "url" => upload.url(:original),
      "delete_url" => upload_path(self),
      "delete_type" => "DELETE" 
    }
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

get rid of all that upload stuff and change it just :upload so

```
params.require(:upload).permit(:post_id,:upload)
```